# How to oneway sync oracle db with external system(Oracle AQ)?

Tags: oracle, synchronization

I want to sync/send data from an oracle to another system via an OData Service, i.e. the data in the oracle needs to be mainly 
replicated in another system (possible the ids of the replicated data in the other system need to be stored in the oracle as well). So the communication would always be initiated by the oracle system.
To cope with possible network outtages and the like it is probably not the post idea to implement a simple send. I need a mechanism that queues the messages until they have have been successfully processed.
What is the way to implement this? 
My supervisor suggested some kind of sync table, because they have done something like in the past in my company. I tried to read up on how to sync and possibly the way to go would be to use messaging queues or to be more exact Oracle Advanced Queuing. Maybe someone can give some advice whether it is achievable and reasonably to implment something like the following with Oracle AQ (I am open for other options):
Record of table that needs replication gets inserted/updated. Trigger fires, writes message (to be send later via ODAta) to the message queue. Another process is scheduled to process the message queue very x-minutes, tries to send data to the other system, if successful message gets removed from queue, if not repeat later in case of network error or leave in queue of manual processing in case of other error.
Any ideas advice, ideas or examples are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AQ is a simple (free) solution to this.  Here's a rudimentary demo

```
--
-- Setup
--

SQL> create or replace type demo_t as object ( x number , y number );
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> begin
  2      dbms_aqadm.create_queue_table (
  3             queue_table=>'DEMO_QT',
  4             queue_payload_type=>'DEMO_T'
  5             --,sort_list=>'PRIORITY,ENQ_TIME'
  6             );
  7
  8      dbms_aqadm.create_queue (
  9             queue_name => 'DEMO_Q',
 10             queue_table => 'DEMO_QT');
 11
 12      dbms_aqadm.start_queue (
 13         queue_name => 'DEMO_Q');
 14  end;
 15  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Enqueue code (the kind of thing you would have in the trigger

```
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_enqueue_options    dbms_aq.enqueue_options_t;
  3    l_message_properties dbms_aq.message_properties_t;
  4    l_msgid              raw(16);
  5  BEGIN
  6      dbms_aq.enqueue(
  7          queue_name => 'DEMO_Q',
  8          enqueue_options => l_enqueue_options,
  9          message_properties => l_message_properties,
 10          payload =>demo_t(10,20),
 11          msgid => l_msgid);
 12  end;
 13  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Dequeue code - what your agent/daemon would run to dispatch messages to another target.

```
SQL>
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> declare
  2     l_dequeue_options    dbms_aq.dequeue_options_t;
  3     l_message_properties dbms_aq.message_properties_t;
  4     l_msgid              RAW(16);
  5     l_message            demo_t;
  6  begin
  7     loop
  8       dbms_aq.dequeue(queue_name         => 'DEMO_Q',
  9                       dequeue_options    => l_dequeue_options,
 10                       message_properties => l_message_properties,
 11                       payload            => l_message,
 12                       msgid              => l_msgid);
 13
 14       dbms_output.put_line( l_message.x);
 15       commit;
 16       --
 17       -- normally this would be an endless loop,
 18       -- but we'll exit here just for demo purposes
 19       --
 20       exit;
 21     end loop;
 22  end;
 23  /
10

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That gives me a good starting point. When dequeuing, is it possible to peek at the message before actually dequeuing? I am still look for a way to cope with the possibility that sending the message does not work, and then I would need to leave the message in the queue for handling it later. Or what would be the best practice to handle this?

Comment: I guess the use of dequeue_options.dequeue_mode := DBMS_AQ.BROWSE; and dequeue_options.dequeue_mode := DBMS_AQ.REMOVE; should allow me to do exactly what I want as explains in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/appdev.816/a76938/adq_aex3.htm#31072

Comment: That's correct.  But hopefully you have some control over the transactional semantics as well.  A more typical method would be: (1) dequeue, (2) attempt operation, (3) if success, then commit, if error, the rollback (and hence the msg stays on the queue).

Comment: That's true. Thanks a lot!